# Which Google API is used to get the Sites owned by the users

Tags: google-sites, sites

I have a question, I have gone through Google Sites API and Report API as well. but im not getting which all sites are owned by user and which are sites user has access to or domain wise access to...

is there any API available for this?

Need quick help.. Thanks a lot in advance...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SitesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app)?
You can retrieve all the sites, and query the ownership and other share settings using the Site class.